# What happens if a question is edited after we answer it?

Tags: discussion, editing

Once, what happened is I answered a question which obviously I thought as an appropriate answer to that question. But after some time, the question was edited by the 'asker' itself. The edit changed the slight meaning of the question. Although it didn't affect the question much. But what about my answer?. I got many down-votes for my answer (which was appropriate before the editing of the question). This is something **unfair** and shouldn't happen. Now, what can one do if He/She is in my position?

Comment: Delete your answer and all the downvotes will be deleted along with it. Even if you roll back the edit to the question as DavidZ suggests, it's very unlikely your downvoters will come back to remove the downvote. Just shrug and move on. It's happened to most of us, and to me several times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can (and should) do is edit your answer to match the updated question.

Now, if the question is edited *drastically*, so much that it's asking something *completely* different and thus invalidates any answers that have been posted, that's a different story. That's not supposed to happen. So in that case you can roll back the edit to the question. If you're not sure whether the edit is drastic enough to qualify for rolling back, you can ask for a second opinion in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar) or here on meta.

Comment: As @JohnRennie commented, rolling back the question is not likely to get the downvotes reversed. Also, sometimes the OP might make a mistake in how the question was originally asked, especially if language is an issue. For example, a misplaced "not", or a slightly mis-formed sentence, or a detail that was inadvertently left out or unknown at the time the question was originally asked. If these are legitimately corrected, it could have a big effect on what would be considered an appropriate answer. So why would you roll back the question to something the OP is not really asking (anymore)...

Comment: ... This is likely to result in an edit war on the question, and any answers to the rolled back question are not going to really address the OPs actual (new) question. Plus, there may be answers that address the edited (new) question which would no longer be valid and may get downvoted because of it. It seems better to leave the edited question alone and let the users delete their downvoted answer (and start again if appropriate).

Comment: Perhaps the real solution would be to roll back the question and have the OP ask the "edited" question as a new question, but for an inexperienced user that might be unlikely. And still there may be some conflicting answers that remain.